# An induced emf problem. Help!

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

[image]

This is the problem.

According to the solution, the "no connection point(or the seeming intersection point) divides them into two loops. And they say that since the flux induced in the right hand side is more, the emf will be according to application of Lenz's law in this loop.

I don't think this is quite true since emf is the tendency to circulate the current, so we would have to integrate it all around but I am not much profound in it so I don't know.

Comment: literally a textbook example of homework problem...

Comment: [This](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/9084/32426) is for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is correct : the direction of the current is decided by the bigger loop.

The magnetic field seems to be uniform in space, so the flux through each loop is simply $BA$ where $A$ is area, and the rate of change of flux = induced emf is $A\frac{dB}{dt}$. The induced emfs are opposed because the areas have the opposite sense : if you trace one loop clockwise you will be tracing anti-clockwise in the other.

There is no need to integrate around the loop. You just add the emfs from each loop algebraically : one is +ve, the other is -ve.

Comment: Adding the two is implicitly integrating about the loops, but quicker. The conclusion (which you did not draw) is that the "bigger emf will win" - that is, the net emf is the sum of the two. Incidentally, as this is a closed circuit the current needs to circulate the same everywhere. This makes a number of the given answers wrong "on sight", leaving only (a) and (c) as possible answers.